# how to enable editing mode on UITableViewCell programmatically?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios6, ios7

I am developing an app which has a `PageViewController` and two view controllers as children of it. One of the Child View controllers has a `UITableView`.

The problem occurs when I swipe the child view controller. I want to have two functionalities like there should be a swipe for delete on tableView.
  When I swipe the child view controller it sends swipe to pageViewController. So it does not show the delete button when we swipe a table view cell.

I want to have two functionalities on swipe event so that there would be both:

1. Swapping of view
2. Show red delete button on row

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        //delete your data here

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should return `YES` to this method of the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol to tell the tableView your cell can respond to the swipe to let appear the delete button:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}
```

and then delete your data in this method, called when the user taps the delete button:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Remove here your data
        ...
        // This line manages to delete the cell in a nice way
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
}
```